# Partition shows up as a directory under /Volumes but not as partition in the diskutil list

Tags: macos, partitioning

I have a firewire enclosure with a 500GB hard drive in it. There are 3 partitions on the hard drive with the following names:

1. Snow Leopard
2. NTFS
3. HFS

However when I run `ls /Volumes` it gives me this:

```
HFS     HFS 1     Momentus XT   NTFS        Snow Leopard
```

Why does this `HFS 1` partition appear? Running `distil list` does not show any sign of a `HFS 1` partition:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Momentus XT             499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *320.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Snow Leopard            80.0 GB    disk1s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS HFS                     150.0 GB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data NTFS                    89.6 GB    disk1s4
```

I've noticed this behaviour since I set [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/download/) to download all torrents to `/Volumes/HFS/Torrents`. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.
I have simply deleted the `HFS 1` folder with `rm -rf` as it was empty, but I'm still wondering where it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/Volumes is really just a regular folder (that OS X happens to use to mount additional volumes). As a result of this, if you have Transmission set to download to /Volumes/HFS/Torrents, but the HFS volume isn't mounted, it will create a regular folder named "HFS" inside /Volumes (and it's just a regular folder on your startup volume). Then, when you connect up the FireWire disk and OS X goes to mount the HFS volume, it looks in /Volumes, notices that the name "HFS" is already taken, and mounts the volume named "HFS" as "/Volumes/HFS 1" to avoid a conflict. (Note: it would do something very similar if you had two volumes named "HFS" mounted.)

In order to fix this, you need to stop Transmission, delete/rename the /Volumes/HFS folder, then dismount and remount the HFS volume, then restart Transmission (and *never ever* start Transmission when the HFS volume isn't mounted, or this'll happen again).